# Images are being displayed vertically, but instead of horizontally?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm having some trouble trying to get the images that are being displayed from the database to display horizontally. I tried using `inline-block`, but that doesn't seem to help at all. I also tried looking at other answers and no luck with my situation.

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "photos");
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY RAND()";
        $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo'<div class="hero">
              <div class="hero-content">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="social-img hide-750">
                    <div class="social-content">
                      <img src="img/'.$row["images"].'">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>';
        }
```

And here is the CSS:

```
    .hero {
  margin-top: -30px;
}
.hero .hero-content {
  margin: -10px auto 0;
  max-width: 1000px;
 /* padding: 50px 20px 170px;*/
}
.hero .hero-content h1 {
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.hero .hero-content h2 {
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.hero .hero-content .row {
 /* margin-top: 60px;*/
}
.hero .hero-content .row .social-img {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #e5e5e5;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 80px;
  width: 29%;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
}
.hero .hero-content .row .social-img .social-content {
  margin: 10px;
}
.hero .hero-content .row .social-img .social-content img {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.hero .hero-content .row .social-img .social-content p {
  color: #505e67;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.hero .hero-content .row .social-img .share .fa {
  color: #bababa;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.hero .hero-content .row .social-img .share .fa:hover {
  color: #f17e6f;
}
@media (max-width: 990px) {
  .hero .hero-content .row .social-img {
    width: 44%;
  }
  .hero .hero-content .row .social-img.hide-990 {
    display: none;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .hero .hero-content {
    padding: 70px 100px 220px;
  }
  .hero .hero-content .row .social-img {
    margin: 0 0 70px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .hero .hero-content .row .social-img.hide-750 {
    display: none;
  }
  .hero .hero-content .row .social-img .social-content img {
    max-height: inherit;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 575px) {
  .hero .hero-content {
    padding: 70px 20px 200px;
  }
  .hero .hero-content h1 {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}
```

I don't understand why it's displaying every image vertically.

Comment: each iteration in the loop is generating a new div (`class="hero"`) so each image is within a new instance of this div. Put that div outside the loop.

Comment: I thought about that @RamRaider. How would that look? Would I have to open and close multiple php tags?

Comment: I am talking about the CSS for `.hero`, `.hero .hero-content`, ' .hero .hero-content .row' and `.social-content` - all the ancestor elements of that image. They all need to be inline-blocks, otherwise they have 100% width. (BTW, it's not clear why you use so many wrappers that contain nothing else than an image - you could combine all these in *one*  DIV)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this ( I think there was also an extra closing div tag in original code btw )

```
    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "photos");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY RAND()";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    if( $result && mysqli_num_rows( $result ) > 0 ){
        echo '<div class="hero">';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo'
            <div class="row">
                <div class="social-img hide-750">
                    <div class="social-content">
                        <img src="img/'.$row["images"].'">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
```

Changing the css rules to remove the class `.hero-content` such as below seems to yield a more desirable result

```
.hero {
  margin-top: -30px;
}
.hero .hero-content {
    margin: -10px auto 0;
  max-width: 1000px;
 /* padding: 50px 20px 170px;*/
}
.hero h1 {
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.hero h2 {
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 200;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.hero .row {
 /* margin-top: 60px;*/
}
.hero .row .social-img {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-color: #e5e5e5;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 20px 80px;
  width: 29%;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
}
.hero .row .social-img .social-content {
  margin: 10px;
}
.hero .row .social-img .social-content img {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.hero .row .social-img .social-content p {
  color: #505e67;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', Arial, Sans-Serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.hero .row .social-img .share .fa {
  color: #bababa;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.hero .row .social-img .share .fa:hover {
  color: #f17e6f;
}
```

Comment: Alright I tried this, now it looks scattered.  That's odd

Comment: the css rules do not follow the html structure. You have `.hero .hero-content .row ` but there is no structure to follow that rule...

Comment: Oh i see. Sorry! `<div class='hero-content'>` goes right under `class='hero'`.

Comment: I am still seeing images vertically with this code... @RamRaider

Answer (score 0):

DIVs are block elements which by default have 100% width of their parent element. You have to make those containers inline-blocks - but *all* of them which should be displayed next to each other, not just the inner container.